# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 with preinstalled Windows 10 Dell G5 5587

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, dell, windows-10

I am trying to install+dual boot Ubuntu 16.04(LTS) with pre installed Windows 10(home) in my Dell G5 5587. Windows is installed in SSD. I have 1TB HDD alongside the SSD.

I did the following:

- Freed 100 GB from SSD and created 100 GB unallocated space.
- Turned off Windows 10 Fast boot.
- Turned off Secure boot feature from BIOS.
- Changed Secure boot mode to audit mode in BIOS.

`msinfo32` is showing:

```
BIOS Mode           UEFI
Secure Boot State   Off
```

The BIOS is showing UEFI on, Secure Boot off, PTT on.

**Approach 1 (MBR+UEFI/Legacy)**

I burned Ubuntu using Rufus(MBR+UEFI/Legacy) to a pendrive. I got the pendrive in the one time boot menu(<kbd>F12</kbd>). When I try to install Ubuntu it showed the following warning:

> "This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it
>   looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed
>   using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in
>   UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any
>   BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>
> If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the
>   ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to
>   force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing
>   operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation
>   here.")

[image: Force UEFI installation]

As I do not want to risk losing Windows, I aborted installing Ubuntu.

**Approach 2 (GPT+UEFI)**

If I burn the Ubuntu OS using Rufus(GPT+UEFI), I do not find the pendrive in one time boot menu(F12).

**Question**

How to properly install dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with pre installed Windows 10 in Dell G5 5587?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside pre installed Windows 10 as dual boot in NVMe SSD.

#### Hardware Information:

- Dell G5 5587
- Core i7 8750H
- RAM 16 GB
- NVMe SSD (Toshiba) 256 GB
- HDD 1 TB
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5 with Max-Q Design

#### Download Files

- Download Ubuntu iso file from [Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
- Download Rufus from [Rufus website](https://rufus.ie/).

#### Burn the ISO to a Pendrive

- Insert a USB pendrive.
- Backup the pendrive data if necessary.
- Open Rufus.
- Select Partition Scheme `MBR`.
- Keep the other settings to default. E.g.: FAT.
- Select the ISO and burn it to the connected pendrive.

#### Create Unallocated Space for Ubuntu

- Open disk management in Windows.
- Shrink the volume where Windows is installed (NVMe SSD). The size depends on yourself. I have created 100 GB of unallocated space.

#### Turn off Fast startup from Windows 10

- Dual boot does not work when Fast startup option is enabled in Windows 10.
- Right-click the `Start` button.
- Click `Search`.
- Type `Control Panel` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.
- Click `Power Options`.
- Click `Choose what the power buttons do`.
- Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.
- Uncheck `Turn on fast startup (recommended)`.
- Click `Save changes`.

#### Turn off secure boot from BIOS

- Tap <kbd>F2</kbd> key at the Dell logo screen to enter System Setup or BIOS.
- On the left pane, click `Boot Sequence`.
- Check that Secure Boot is set to Disabled. Within the BIOS go to `Secure Boot` > `Secure Boot Enable`, and set the checkbox to `Disabled`.
- Change the `Secure Boot Mode` to `audit mode`.
- Save settings and the machine will be restarted.

#### Enable AHCI for dual boot

- With a preinstalled Windows SATA mode set to IDE or RAID in BIOS.
- To install dual boot we need to change SATA mode to AHCI from BIOS.
- Create the Windows 10 local account:

  - Go to Settings > Accounts.
  - Select `Family & other users.`
  - Tap `Add someone else to this PC.`
  - Select `I don't have this person's sign-in information.`
  - Select `Add a user without a Microsoft account.`
  - Enter a username, type the account's password twice, enter a clue and select Next.
  - Change the `Account type` of this newly created account to `Administrator`.
  - Login using this new user account.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup. On Dell Inspiron it is <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Change the `SATA Operation mode` to `AHCI` from either `IDE` or `RAID`.
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

#### Install Ubuntu

- After the OS burn, insert the pendrive and restart the machine.
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> depending your machine.
- Select USB/Removable media.
- Select install Ubuntu.
- Select Language and other options.
- When it comes to partition option, select `something else`.
- In the unallocated space:

  - Give 2 GB Logical space to swap memory. The swap size depends on your RAM size.
  - Give remaining Primary space to `/` partition
- Select `Windows Boot Manager` as `Device for boot loader installation`.
- Continue with the remaining process.

#### Install Drivers (optional)

- After successful installation of Ubuntu, update the system softwares.
- To update the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

- You may now access both Windows and Ubuntu in a dual boot manner.

#### Reference:

- [Turn off fast startup Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup)
- [Dual boot in NVMe SSD Dell](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Dual-booting-Windows-10-and-Ubuntu-17-04-on-NVMe-SSD-Dell/td-p/5110983)
- [Turn off secure boot from Dell BIOS](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln142679/how-to-enable-boot-from-dvd-option-with-uefi-boot-mode-enabled-windows-10-8-1-8?lang=en)
- [Create local account in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/limited-user-accounts-windows-10)
- [Dell documentation on creating dual boot](https://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/sln301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-windows-8-or-10-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks, this was super useful.

Comment: This approach has been the most successful for me so far, though I created a Root at /, swap partition at /swap, and the remainder of the logical free space as /home

Comment: The process failed for me when I went to select "Device for boot loader installation." and there was no "Windows Boot Manager". So I looked up where this would be, finding out it would be in the Windows system partition, which on my machine is /dev/nvme0n1p1. That's what I set it to, though received the warning "The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved Bios Boot Area" and should be at least 1 MB in size."

Comment: @arsho (or anyone else who might know) There is one free space of 1 MB at the beginning of the original /dev/nvme0n1 portion of the drive, should I load it there, or some other partition?

Comment: Worked, this is the most successful. On Dell G5 5550 Nividia geforce GTX.

Comment: Upvoted for enable ahci controller. Still works with some minor flow related changes in Win 11)